# Set multiple header to be fixed at top of the page while scrolling by using jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have an scenario where for Example i am having calendar with 12 months and i m having month name as header tag if i scroll the window the header of each month should be fixed at the top of the window.

If my current month is say FEB the FEB header should fix and content of the FEB should scroll up until the MARCH header comes to the top.

Hope Understood the scenario.

Kindly guide me

I have tried

HTML Page:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.blk_area').eq(0).addClass('current');
  $('.current ul').addClass('top_pos');
  $('.current .hdr_cnt').removeClass('relative');
  $('.current .hdr_cnt').addClass('fixed');

  var previousScroll = 0;

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {

      var curElem = $('.current');
      var nextElem = curElem.next();
      var index = nextElem.index();
      var top_pos = nextElem.offset().top - wScroll;

      if (top_pos == 1) {
        curElem.removeClass('current');
        $('.current .hdr_cnt').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.current ul').removeClass('top_pos')
        curElem.hide();

        nextElem.addClass('current');
        $('.current .hdr_cnt').removeClass('relative');
        $('.current .hdr_cnt').addClass('fixed');
        $('.current ul').addClass('top_pos');
      }
    } else {
      console.log('up');
      var nextEle = $('.current').prev();
      var index = $('.current').prev().index();
      console.log(nextEle, index);
    }
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
  });
});
```

```css
.logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.bird-box {
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(1.jpg) top center;
}
ul {
  padding: 0px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
.current .hdr_cnt {
  width: 98.8%;
  top: 2px;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.top_pos {
  margin-top: 205px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blk_area">
  <div class="hdr_cnt relative">
    <header class="bird-box ">
      <div class="logo">Bird BOX</div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>JAN - 01</li>
    <li>JAN - 02</li>
    <li>JAN - 03</li>
    <li>JAN - 04</li>
    <li>JAN - 05</li>
    <li>JAN - 06</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="blk_area">
  <div class="hdr_cnt relative">
    <header class="bird-box">
      <div class="logo">FEB</div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>FEB - 01</li>
    <li>FEB - 02</li>
    <li>FEB - 03</li>
    <li>FEB - 04</li>
    <li>FEB - 05</li>
    <li>FEB - 06</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="blk_area">
  <div class="hdr_cnt">
    <header class="bird-box">
      <div class="logo">MAR</div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>MAR - 01</li>
    <li>MAR - 02</li>
    <li>MAR - 03</li>
    <li>MAR - 04</li>
    <li>MAR - 05</li>
    <li>MAR - 06</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks